# Adding text to the body of an email

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to add some default text to the body of the email. Can i change the font and the colour of the font used ?

Answer (score 4):

You can specify isHTML = yes and format your email text using HTML tags.

Comment: When i am using HTML tags, Could i specify <html> <head> <body> tags too ?

Comment: You can. But you don't have to I think.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  You will have to provide it as HTML, and you should pass `YES` as the `isHTML` argument to `setMessageBody:isHTML:`.

Comment: When i am using HTML tags, Could i specify <html> <head> <body> tags too

Comment: Yes, but mail client support for HTML is very hit and miss.  This is a large topic, I suggest you start with [Campaign Monitor's resources](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/) and [MailChimp's resources](http://mailchimp.com/resources/).